# Watch FTP directory changes, then send to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp

I have a Rails app that has a strict requirement of receiving XML files via FTP on port 21.

I have FTP server set up to receive files (outside of the rails app), however I am having trouble finding solutions where I can have uploaded files be sent to my rails app so that they can be processed.

Is there a way to host an FTP server inside a rails app? Is there a way to watch arbitrary folders for changes and processes them?

I am running Rails `4.2.5`, Ruby `2.3.1` on a Ubuntu `14.04` server.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is this:

- Make sure your Rails app can access the dir where XML files are uploaded. (No FTP required here)
- Write a Ruby class (`lib/xml_watcher.rb` for instance) that checks the directory for XML files, and processes them accordingly. Ideally, if you're using Resque, all you need to do is schedule a new job for each file.
- Create a rake task that executes above Ruby class
- Schedule a cronjob to periodically execute the above rake task

update: there are more advanced solutions that use IO events to instantly get notification of changed files. This is nice, of course, but it also adds quite a lot of complexity. I prefer the simple *just works* solution.